# Image measure - transportation of expectation (change of variable formula)

Tags: measure-theory

In the "base case" of the proof of the change of variable formula, we have the following setting:

$(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ a probability space, 
$h$ a measurable function from this probability space to $(S, \mathcal{S})$.

And it is written: For $B \in \mathcal{S}$

$\int_S 1_B d (h \circ P) < \infty$ iff $\int_{\Omega} (1_B \circ h) dP$

is obvious, where $(h \circ P)(A):=P[h^{-1}(A)]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{S}$.

can you help me proving that this is obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of an indicator function $\mathbf{1}_B$ is just the measure of $B$, by definition. Therefore
$$
\int_S \mathbf{1}_B \, d(h \circ P)
= (h \circ P)(B)
= P[h^{-1}(B)].
$$
Similarly, $\mathbf{1}_B \circ h = \mathbf{1}_{h^{-1}(B)}$ (since $h(\omega) \in B$ if and only if $\omega \in h^{-1}(B)$), so
$$
\int_\Omega (\mathbf{1}_B \circ h) \, dP
= \int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_{h^{-1}(B)} \, dP
= P[h^{-1}(B)].
$$
Therefore $\int_S \mathbf{1}_B \, d(h \circ P) = \int_\Omega (\mathbf{1}_B \circ h) \, dP$.